# Wordpress how to remove article element white background

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm trying to remove the white-background of wordpress Article (page), NOT the body background, the element's background. I would that the article text has no white background, but only the body background.

I've tryed so many "external css" but no one worked for me.

```
   article.post-1 { //just an example, I've tryed many other elements
     background-color: transparent;
   }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tiFw.jpg You can see the white background behind the TEXT, i would remove that white and see the TEXT directly on the background image. It's in the homepage.

Comment: That will depend on which theme you're using. You can use your browser's debug tools to work out which element this is and what CSS classes it has.

Comment: Do you have your website link? or post the relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: Please post your HTML

Comment: if this doesn't remove the background color, look at the parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved that by adding a !important after my css code:

```
element {

 background-color: transparent !important;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should inspect the code of the page to find out the class where the background is applied, then you can set background: transparent (and not background-color, because it only works with color values).

Comment: [The MDN article for background-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) says that `background-color: transparent` is fine, either as a special keyword or as a color (since 'transparent' has been adopted as a color value) depending on which standards you're looking at.